# How can one synthesise a conjugated alkyne chain?

Tags: synthesis

Let's take the conjugated alkyne chain (e) below, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkyne):

> [image]

How would one typically go about synthesising such a conjugated chain with a series of alkyne functions?

Answer (score 13):

A carbenoid Fritsch-Buttenberg-Wiechell (FBW) rearrangement of a substituted dibromoolefinic precursor is used to generate a lithium acetylide, and subsequent trapping with carbon-based electrophiles provides a wide range of di- and triynes. The lithium acetylide formed from the FBW reaction can also undergo transmetalation to provide zinc, copper, tin, or platinum acetylides [[1](https://doi.org/10/ffbmwt)]. The paper described the preparation of poly-ynes of up to 6 triple bond units.

> [image: FBW reaction]

<sup>Image source: [organic-chemistry.org](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/C1C/chains/alkynes.shtm)</sup>

#### References

1. Luu, T.; Morisaki, Y.; Cunningham, N.; Tykwinski, R. R. One-Pot Formation and Derivatization of Di- and Triynes Based on the Fritsch−Buttenberg−Wiechell Rearrangement. *J. Org. Chem.* **2007**, 72 (25), 9622–9629. https://doi.org/10.1021/jo701810g .

Comment: Limiting the target to diynes I mention the earlier still valuable oxidative coupling of terminal alkynes, copper catalysed, in air.